# MySQL: highlight rows in table1 that cannot a found on table2

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

Let's say...

### Table1

```
id   amount    ref#
1    100.00    123
2    150.00    524
3    200.00    569
```

### Table2

```
id   name   ref#
1    john   123
2    alex   524
3    rich   568
4    rico   685
5    toby   456
6    rick   258
```

Now i want to view all records in Table1, and highlight the rows where ref# in Table1 cannot be found in Table2 ref# . So the result in a jtable should be..

```
id   amount    ref#
1    100.00    123
2    150.00    524
3    200.00    569     <-- being highlighted
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a join to compare your tables, ie something to the extend of:

```
SELECT id, amount, a.ref, b.ref
FROM table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.ref = b.ref
```

You can then use the results where `b.ref == null` to highlight any results that exist in table1, but not in table2. if `b.ref != null` it means there is a result for both tables.

Hope this helps.